# What’s this PCB that interfaces with the USB CarPlay connector of the Ioniq 5 / EV6?

Tags: automotive, usb-device, electric-vehicle

As with several owners of [the Hyundai Ioniq 5](https://www.ioniqforum.com/threads/illustrated-guide-to-replacing-carplay-android-usb-port.44048/page-6?nested_view=1&sortby=oldest) and the [Kia EV6](https://youtu.be/326U3NhwMnM?si=qApKjSzKzhkNaMXI), I’ve been having intermittent issues with the USB CarPlay functionality. It worked fine when the car was new, but after a few months the connection became unstable. While the dealer insists this doesn’t happen with their test phone and cable, I’ve seen the CarPlay system working fine for a few minutes and even hours before suddenly disconnecting.

Many owners have reported changing the internal USB cable assembly fixed the issue (p/n 96120-GI000). Others mentioned simply reconnecting the internal connectors solved the issue. However a few owners report the issue coming back after a few months. Last, some owners report a link in disconnections with using the heater in winter. So what’s going on here?

After unsuccessfully trying to get the dealer to fix this, I investigated further and saw an interesting printed circuit next to the USB receptacle. Attached to the circuit, on the opposite side of the USB receptacle, are two cables, one with a blue connector going to the infotainment unit (4 pins) and one with a white connector (4 pins too, but different shape) going to a small 4 cable loom.

The bottom left section of the PCB (when viewed from the top) seems electrically independent of the rest. From my tests, this portion of the circuit only powers a small LED (D2) to help the vehicle occupants find the USB receptacle.

Then the rest of the PCB seems to carry the power and data lines into the infotainment unit. I see a few parts for ESD protection. Then there’s F1 which is inline with the data pins of the USB connector. Interestingly, the measured resistance across F1 for each data line was about 3 ohms. Could this be a fuse, PTC or some other type of protection device?

The back side of the PCB shows more components including Q1, which I’m not sure the purpose.

**Could this PCB be responsible for the intermittent CarPlay connectivity?** Or could it be due to something else? Would love to understand what this circuit does.

[image: Top PCB with part F1]

[image: Bottom PCB with part Q1]

## 1-month later update

After reassembling the USB cable assy, lubricating the connector and replugging into the main infotainment unit, I haven’t experienced any CarPlay disconnects. It’s possible the factory routing of the cable passed too close to other signal cables and caused interference, or maybe the connector wasn’t properly plugged in?

Comment: I don't think the pictures can provide enough info. It is not even clear how the power supply ends up to the connector, through Q1 or on the top side. F1 is likely just a common mode choke. You would need equipment that costs approximately as much as the car to analyze signal integrity issues caused by this board.

Comment: F prefix normally means fuse. Alternatively, filter on rare occasions. Very good photos by the way!

Comment: @justme The cable with blue connector going to the infotainment unit has 4 pins just like USB type A. It’s epoxied into the bottom right of the PCB. I measured the resistance from the blue connector in the cable assy up to the USB receptacle. V+ and GND showed close to 0 ohm, but the data lines showed 3 ohms because of the F1 part.

Comment: @Honeycomb It does not tell anything if you measure with a multimeter. You can get close to 0 ohms but USB2 runs at up to 480 megabits per second, requiring analog bandwidth multiple times 480 MHz. And data wires require 90 ohms of characteristic impedance, i.e. what the electrical waves of the signal pulses see. Measuring DC ohms of 3 over a common mode is not surprising, but we cannot know what component that is and whether it is supposed to measure 3 ohms or something else.

Comment: Is it possible to replace this PCB with a short couple inch extension cord and run it in your car for a while to see if the problem persists or not?

Comment: Connection issues occurring after some months are probably corrosion-related. It's hard to find the specific location, and even if you find it, sometimes hard to repair it.